# Communicating across different Sheet files

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Excuse my poor terminology, I'm a casual Sheets user.

I have a business with 5 different, somewhat complicated revenue streams. So I made a budget sheet for each of them. I end up with a GROSS PROFIT for each revenue stream.

Now I want to create a "Master Budget" Sheet that pulls the final GROSS PROFIT numbers from each of the 5 Sheets, but I can't figure out how to get the Master sheet "to pull" the numbers from the other Sheets.

thx

Answer (score 0):

#### How to pull value from another cell

---

**Assumptions:**

- In **Google Sheets**<sup>1</sup> you have a **spreadsheet**<sup>2</sup> with the URL
  ["https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z11UOsQrxBqWrerZuO6FSQrxbH3qw2R_s5zUOfS/edit"](http://#)
- Your **spreadsheet** contains a **sheet**<sup>3</sup> named **Sheet1**
- **Sheet1** contains a **source** cell at 'A1' with a **value** of 44
- You have a **target** cell into which you will place a **formula** that dynamically returns the **value** of the **source** cell

#### Formula in Target

---

1. If the **target** cell is in the same **sheet** as the **source** cell:

```
 =cell
 =A1
 =44
```

2. If the **target** cell is in a different **sheet** than the **source** cell, but they are both in the same **spreadsheet**:<sup>4</sup>

```
='sheetName'!cell 
=Sheet1!A1
=44
```

3. If the **target** cell is in a different **spreadsheet** than the  **source** cell, you need to use the **IMPORTRANGE**<sup>5</sup> function.  Since our range consists of only one cell (1x1) I could optionally define the **range** as 'A1' instead of the normal 'A1:A1' notation:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_url, range_string) =IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z11UOsQrxBqWrerZuO6FSQrxbH3qw2R_s5zUOfS/edit", "Sheet1!A1")
=44
```

#### Notes on Quotes

---

**Single Quotes**
Sheet names need to be wrapped in single quotation marks (') if there are any spaces in the name

```
  =Sheet1!A1     // valid
  ='Sheet 1'!A1  // valid
  =Sheet 1!A1    // #ERROR
```

**Double Quotes**
spreadsheet_url and range_strings need to wrapped in double quotation marks (")

```
  =IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/...", "Sheet1!A1")   // valid
  =IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/...", 'Sheet1!A1')   // #ERROR
  =IMPORTRANGE('https://docs.google.com/...', "Sheet1!A1")   // #ERROR
  =IMPORTRANGE(https://docs.google.com/..., "Sheet1!A1")     // #ERROR
  =IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/...", Sheet1!A1)     // #ERROR
  =IMPORTRANGE(https://docs.google.com/..., Sheet1!A1)       // #ERROR
```

#### Footnotes

---

<sub>1. Google **Sheets** is a web-based application to create, update and modify and share Google **spreadsheets**. [Link to Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/)</sub>
<sub>2. A Google **spreadsheet** is a file containing one or more **sheets**.</sub>
<sub>3. A **sheet** in Google **Sheets** (the app) is analogous to a page. A newly created **spreadsheet** will have only one, and it will be named **Sheet1**. A **sheet** can be renamed, added, deleted, moved, and duplicated. You can switch to another by clicking on the other **sheet**'s tab. Some people use the words **sheet** and **tab** interchangeably.</sub>
<sub>4. How to reference data from other **sheets** in the same **spreadsheet** [support.google.com/docs/answer/75943](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75943)</sub>
<sub>5. How to import a **range** of cells from a specified **spreadsheet**  [support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)</sub>

Comment: So I tried both things and I'm getting errors.  I'm sure I'm doing it wrong, so I have a couple questions:   1) is a Different Sheet just another tab in the same Sheet, or a different file. I'm thinking the former. 2) so then what I'm trying to do, is reference a value in a separate File, and your instructions are to copy the File URL and then put the file name in ' '.  Correct?   When I do that I get a "formula parse error". thx

Comment: I made an error in #3 that I've since corrected. I've updated the answer with additional explanations.  Hope that helps.

Comment: THANK YOU!  That did it.  Much appreciated

Comment: That's great Jeff!  Since you are new to the community, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)  If it solved your problem mark it as accepted so others will benefit as well when searching. :-)